# Google Chrome autofill not working on Google Forms responses

Tags: google-chrome

After reading about Google Chrome's Autofill feature to enable filling in forms data much quicker, I decided to give it a try. When booking courier companies to transport out orders, it works perfectly and saves me heaps of time. I have found it frustrating however, that it will not work on Google forms responses. We have many respondents to a Google forms responses sheet we have set up and each week, the respondents have to input the same data week after week without being able to use the Autofill features they have set up in Google Chrome. Is there a reason for this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML source on a Google Form I saw that it doesn't look like they are using a standard HTML forms to create the form or it's input fields.  The input fields appear to be created using designated class attributes.  The Chrome browser is looking to autofill / autocomplete an HTML input form field.  Based on the type of form input field it presents what it thinks you would like to fill it with (text, phone, etc..).  This is just my best guess after reading this SO question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome